# Transaction Scope with Access Database

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, transactionscope

I am using Access Database with c# windows application. My application uses different methods to update different tables of database. I want to make my code block transactional but access do not support TransactionScope. Is there any other way of doing this?

My Existing Code sample:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                //If customer exists update it else Register new customer
                if (Customer.IsCustomerExists(cname) == true)
                    Customer.UpdateCustomerInfo(cname, cell, mobile, phone);
                else
                    Customer.RegisterNewCustomer(cname, cell, mobile, phone);

                //If source station not exists, Register new station
                if (Station.IsStationExists(source) == false)
                    Station.RegisterNewStation(source);

                //If destination station not exists, Register new station
                if (Station.IsStationExists(destination) == false)
                    Station.RegisterNewStation(destination);

                scope.Complete();
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "single round trip" and what does that have to do with `TransactionScope` ?

Comment: The Jet driver doesn't support transactions.  You have to use a different data store.